# Is it possible to use QFile::map with mmap MAP_POPULATE flag?

Tags: linux, qt, mmap

I am using QFile map function in an application in on linux. The default behaviour is of course mmap's default, lazy loading of data. I'd prefer to map the file with mmap MAP_POPULATE flag, but can't find any way to do so in Qt API. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using QFile::readAll() will do the trick.

After opening the file, and then mapping it, just call the readAll() function on the QFile object. This will read all of the file in advance. Amazingly, this is only done once. After closing the application,  if you re-run it, you'll see that that the readAll() will be finished in a fraction of second for even quite large files.

Comment: Even better, do `QtConcurrent::run([name]{ QFile f(name); if (f.open(...)) f.readAll(); });` This will read the file in a worker thread from the thread pool, keeping your application responsive.

Comment: The purpose of MAP_POPULATE is to fetch data from disk in advance ("read ahead"), in order to prevent page faults later on. Page faults have a cost, and readAll(), unless being especially smart, will probably trigger a page fault for every sector. That's probably what the asker wanted to avoid. At least that's what I want to avoid, and ended using mmap() directly rather than through QFile.